# Copy excel formula of column in all rows while writing dynamic data from DB in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, excel-formula, excel-2007, maatwebsite-excel

I am using PHP (laravel) for writing data dynamically in excel sheet from database. I have excel sheet in which I have filled data in first row with formula in few columns.

Now what I want, I just want to copy that formula in every respective column dynamically when I am writing data dynamically. I am using maatwebsite for writing the data in excel sheet. See below code.

```
Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(1)->load(public_path('uploads') . '/data.xlsx', function($reader) {
            $reader->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) {
                        // Append row as very last
                        $sheet->appendRow(array(
                            'appended', 'appended' // Here I am appending the dynamic data in my code.
                        ));
                    });
        }, 'UTF-8')->store('xlsx', true);
```

Suppose column `"M"` has formula in first row so whenever new record will fill in this column dynamically that column must contain the same formula. How can I achieve this? Anyone faced this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use like `$sheet->setCellValue('B5','=SUM(B2:B4)');` at the time of writing data on excel file... Hope this will help you...
**UPDATED CODE**

`for($k=1;$k>n;$k++){
 $sheet->setCellValue('AC' . $k, '=SUM(N' . $k . ',O' . $k . ',Q' . $k . ',S' .  $k . ',T' . $k . ',V' . $k . ',Y' . $k . ',AB' . $k . ')');
}`

Comment: But I need to copy the formula of above column to next one.

Comment: you can generate formula dynamically for each row, check my updated answer.

Comment: So there is no way to copy the formula in next cell of excel?

Comment: Let me try for this

Comment: May be there is some other option to achieve this...  but my above solution fulfill your requirement...

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
$rule = ['appended', 'appended']; 
    Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(1)->load(public_path('uploads') . '/data.xlsx', function ($reader) use ($rule) {
        $reader->sheet('Sheetname', function ($sheet) use ($rule) {
            // Append row as very last
            $sheet->appendRow($rule);
        });
    }, 'UTF-8')->store('xlsx', true);
```

Comment: In this way formula will be copy in my column?

Comment: According to you code, you wanted to  append codes 
` $sheet->appendRow(array(
                            'appended', 'appended' // Here I am appending the dynamic data in my code.
                        ));`
 Now you can append the rule dynamically ... assign the rule to the variable ...

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience but I just want to copy the formula of column in next dynamic columns data. See:  Suppose column "M" has formula in first row so whenever new record will fill in this column dynamically that column must contain the same formula.

Comment: Any suggestion on this?

Comment: The formula of the column "M", are you getting it dynamically from the database????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143090/discussion-between-raghbendra-nayak-systematix-and-sarnodeep-agarwalla).